# Input checkbox ridiculously big on iOS Safari

Tags: html, ios, css, checkbox, mobile-safari

Checked my site on iOS Safari and I get this huge checkbox input that looks like it's system styled. Can this be styled, or maybe made a bit smaller?

The issue can be checked [here](http://sai.cuceu.ro/contact/)

[image: 1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `padding` of the checkbox to `0` (or to a value more to your liking).

```css
.gdlr-core-input-wrap.gdlr-core-large input:not([type="button"]):not([type="submit"]):not([type="file"]) {
  /* padding: 20px 22px; */
  padding: 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: that's new for me, I didn't know you can set padding to checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

The Hoffman's solution doesn't work for my website, but this addons in the css does:

@supports (-webkit-touch-callout: none) {
/* CSS specific to iOS devices */
input[type=checkbox] {
-webkit-transform: scale(0.5,0.5);
}
}

Answer (score 0):

With CSS Grid I had to add width and height and line-height to input.