# Padding on iPhone Displays 19px To Left Compared To Desktop

Tags: html, css

I’m trying to use embed this code on Shogun landing page, but I’m having trouble with the padding of a text line.

2nd line “Silver 3x (Save 55%)” on radio button 3 aligns vertically to the left with red “Most Popular” with padding-left: 46px; on desktop.

When I view the page on iPhone, text moves to the left by 19px.

If I change to padding-left: 65px; 2nd line shows up aligned on iPhone, but it’s shifted to the right by 19px on desktop.

I asked Shogun app support and they suggested that it may have something to do with the user agent style sheet but I still can’t figure our the problem.

I tried CSS reset, but it’s not working. Maybe I used it wrong.

Any suggestions?

```css
     /* Radio Buttons */
     #ctable {
       text-align: left;
       border: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
       padding: 15px;
       font-size: 20px;
     }

     th {
       border-color: transparent;
       border-bottom: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
       padding-bottom: 12px;
     }

     td {
       padding: 10px;
       border-color: transparent;
     }

     .button2 {
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }

     .hf {
       cursor: pointer;
     }

     .hf td input[type="radio"] {
       transform: scale(1.3);
       margin-right: 16px;
       margin-left: 10px;
     }

     .highlited {
       box-shadow: 3px 4px 8px 1px #b2afaf;
     }

     .highlited td {
       background-color: #FDF107;
       border: 1px solid black;
     }

     .mp {
       color: red;
       font-size: 25px;
       font-weight: 700;
       display: inline-block;
       margin-bottom: 7px;
     }

     .mpt {
       display: inline-block;
       padding-left: 46px;
     }
```

```html
<div>
<table id="ctable" style="width:100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tr>
   <th>Qty</th><th>Price</th>
 </tr>

 <tr class="hf">
   <td><label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio1"> Silver 1x (50% OFF)</label> </td>
         <td>$9.98</td>
 </tr>

 <tr class="hf">
   <td class="button2"><label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio2"> Silver 2x (50% OFF)</label></td>
         <td class="button2">$9.98</td>
 </tr>

   <tr class="hf highlited">
      <td style="border-right: 0px;">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio3" checked> <span class="mp">Most Popular</span><br /><span class="mpt"> Silver 3x (Save 55%)</span></label>
      </td>
      <td style="border-left: 0px;">$26.97</td>
    </tr>

 <tr class="hf">
   <td><label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio4"> Silver 5x (65% OFF)</label></td>
            <td>$9.98</td>

 </tr>

 <tr class="hf">
   <td><label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio5"> Silver 7x (75% OFF)</label></td>
            <td>$9.98</td>
 </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this post

[Input checkbox ridiculously big on iOS Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55362715/input-checkbox-ridiculously-big-on-ios-safari)

and added padding: 0px; to radio button CSS and it's fixed now!!
Woo hoo!!